# Circular reference with mongokit - is it possible?

Tags: mongokit

I'm having 2 classes Branch & User. User belongs to certain branch. However every branch has a CEO (a type of User). But when I design the mongokit classes and trying to use reference it does work for class User (as branch is defined ahead of User), but it doesn't work for class Branch, getting the following error:

***'ceo': User***
***NameError: name 'User' is not defined***

### So the question - how to achieve such reference?

```
from mongokit import *
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import pprint

db = Connection()

@db.register
class Registry(Document):
    structure = {
        'created': datetime,
        'updated': datetime,
        'deleted': datetime
    }

@db.register
class Branch(Registry):
    structure = {
        'name':unicode,
        'groupEmail':unicode,
        'timezone':unicode,
        'address': {
            'address1':unicode,
            'address2':unicode,
            'city':unicode,
            'state':unicode,
            'country':unicode,
            'zip': unicode
        },
        'size':int,
        'ceo': User
}

@db.register
class User(Document):
    structure = {
        'fname': unicode,
        'lname': unicode,
        'branch': Branch,
        'address': {
            'address1':unicode,
            'address2':unicode,
            'city':unicode,
            'state':unicode,
            'country':unicode,
            'zip': unicode
        },
        'created': datetime,
        'updated': datetime,
        'deleted': datetime
    }
```